# Can I link to a service without hard coding in URL/Port

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Question: Can I access my service's controller via web client without hard coding URL/port to service.

Information:

- web api service running on a localhost port
- web client (mvc, razor) running on localhost, different port
- CORS enabled
- code works, but I dont want hard coded urls

Example AJAX call from client to service:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:12345/api/ModifySystems",
        type: "post",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        datatype: "json",
        data: ko.toJSON({ systems: self.updatedSystem, id: self.id }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) { 
           // do stuff
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {   
           // do stuff
        }
    });
```

As you can see, this AJAX call uses the url:

> http://localhost:12345/api/ModifySystems

Is there a way to change it to dynamically be able to determine "http://localhost:12345"?  Is there a way to make it convenient, similar to "@Url.Action("ModifySystems")"?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the root URL of your service in the config file, then add it to the Model object of your view and output it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Model.RootServiceUrl" + "/api/ModifySystems",
    type: "post",
    ....
```

Comment: I will definitely start doing this because it looks clean and is easier to change, but this still is a static solution rather than dynamic. I still have to hard code the url/port, but I do it in a different spot. 

Thanks for the info though - I like the "static variable" change for the js.

Comment: You'll always have to define the API url *somewhere* as they are two separate applications. For example they could be deployed on different servers or the ports or domain names could change - there's no way for the mvc app to know what the api app's url is automatically.   Putting it in the config means that it only needs to be changed in one place (and a suitable place... configuration in the configuration file) no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: garrett, I don't see how it could be more dynamic than placing the known value of the service's address somewhere in the web app's domain.  Let's say you didn't know where the service was, and your goal was to figure out where a service is listening...  The solutions I can come up with for that are messy and involved at best.  Config file means change during runtime, so it isn't really considered hard coded, you do not need to recompile the code for a change to config to take effect.